# IndexError: list index out of range, al dar formato

Tags: html, python, json, archivo

Estoy intentando darle formato a un archivo, mi problema es que si dentro de " ", se encuentra una comilla extra (" " ") truena & me lanza este error, mi código es el siguiente:

```
with open(entrada, "r") as fichero:
    datos = fichero.read()
    datos = list(datos)
indice=0
while indice < len(datos):
if datos[indice]=="\"":
    indice+=1
        while (datos[indice]!="\"" and datos[indice+1]!=":") or (datos[indice]!="\"" and datos[indice+1]!=",") or (datos[indice]!="\"" and datos[indice+1]!="}") and (indice+2<len(datos)):
        indice+=1
    if datos[indice]==",":
        datos[indice]=",\n"
    if datos[indice]=="[":
        datos[indice]="[\n"
    if datos[indice]=="{":
        datos[indice]="{\n"
    indice+=1
datos = ''.join(str(e) for e in datos)
```

espero puedan ayudarme, quizas se daran cuenta que es para darle formato a un JSON, & que puedo usar el dump & el load, pero no me sirve ya que estoy intentando darle formato a un JSON que tiene errores de sintaxis.

Comment: Debes tener mucho cuidado cuando incrementas `indice` para que siempre sea menor  a `len(datos)` o a `len(datos) - 1` cuando haces `datos[indice+1]`  . Por ejemplo, si `len(datos)` es 7, e `indice` es 6, si se cumple `if datos[indice]=="\""`: ya tienes un problema en el `while` porque `datos[indice]!="\""` es `datos[7]!="\""` lo cual está fuera de rango.

Comment: Mas que nada el primer if con el while, es para respetar todo lo que se encuentra entre " ", lo único en que me falla es si existen comillas impares

Comment: Aprovecha y refactora. Te das cuenta que `datos[indice]` siempre es diferente a \? Podria ser algo asi:
`while(datos[indice] != '\' and datos[indice+1] not in [':', ',', '}'] ... etc`